# Can not logout correctly since upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, logout

After I upgrade to 14.04, I cannot logout correctly, the system will hang on in black screen(while the cursor is still visible), and I have to run killall -u $USERNAME to get back to lightdm interface.

I find the exactly process hanged my system on is "init", after kill it the system logout correctly.

Anyone get any idea what might cause this issue, or which log file should I look into?

Comment: try Ctrl+Alt+L ..

Comment: No, I mean I can use the "Logout" function, but it just won't work correctly.

Comment: k, I dont know how to solve this.. but do remember fresh clean new installation is always better then Upgrading. So upto some extents its obvious. If you want to enjoy 14.04 then make a fresh install instead of upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've already found out the system was suspended from logging out by fcitx-qimpanel, which get a segment fault after I install sougoupinyin.

So if any other chinese user installed that package find this topic, you might have an answer.